# How can I add JavaScript, CSS, and HTML code together in single html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I add `<script>` and `<style>` in single html body

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>My site title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want css and javascript to be entered in this format

Comment: I don't use to recommend w3schools... but in this case: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: Just a wild idea, but how about adding `<script>` and `<style>` into your HTML body? By the way, you might want to learn the correct spelling of the language you are using. It is "JavaScript".

Comment: what toraz said, but also... don't. Just don't do it. Put your css in a separate .css file. Put your javascript in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 3):

you initialize javascript with the `<script>` tag, and css with the `<style>` tag.

E.g.

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>My site title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('yippie');
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

    red text
  </body>
</html>
```

But depending on your requirements, it might be more advisible to place javascript and css code in the `head` section or even better in separate files, like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>My site title</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `type='text/javascript'` and `type='text/css'` attributes?

Comment: @torazaburo -- they are obsolete as of HTML5 and should _not_ be used. Use plain `<script>` and `<style>` tags. (but don't, put them in their own files.)

Comment: The type attribute identifies the content between the script tags. They are not obsolete, but no longer requiered in HTML5 because they default to <script type="application/javascript"> and <style type="text/css">

Comment: No, the default for script tags is `text/javascript`. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Answer (score 0):

Somehow like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <title>My site title</title>
     <style>
        h1 {
          color: red;
        }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  
  <script>
    alert('script works')
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Put your styles inside `<style>` tag (this tag traditionally goes inside `head`), and put your Javascript code inside `<script>` tag (this tag traditionally goes before `</body>` closing tag, but you can put it afrer `<body>` or inside `<head>` tag, it depends on when you want to initialize your script).

Answer (score 0):

You can use both html elements, css and javascript inside `body` tag. There is no issues. But it is recommended to use css & javascript inside `head`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Your text</div>
  <style>
    div {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    alert('Hello world');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: pls can you give me an example of it

Comment: and i also want to enter html code to it

Comment: Updated the answer with the example

Answer (score 0):

For css use "style" attribute inside the respective html tags.
example:

---

`<h1 style="color:red"> Example text </h1>`

---

or use "style" tag i.e write your css coding inside `<style>` tag in your html file

For javascript use `<script>` tag and write your javascript code inside them.

Above stuffs works fine with small html file but if your html file is very large then it may create clutter so I would suggest you to write your css and javascript codes in separate files and then link them with your html file with `<link>` tag...

Comment: how can i do so can you give me the code with example

Comment: Checkout this- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Answer (score -3):

I assume you want to add a CSS and javascript to a title,which isnt possible,
Unless you meant another thing

Comment: There's a very high probability that your assumption is wrong, but then again who knows.

Comment: no i wanted html code css code and java script in one html body only